# Content access based on on the field reference

Tags: entities, users

I want to make a content access ( node ) based on it's user reference field .
ie: While i'm creating a node that have a user reference field, i want that it will be accessible just for the users that i mentionned before .
Is there any module or a way to do that ?
Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Drupal 7 there's the [Node Access User Reference](http://drupal.org/project/nodeaccess_userreference) module which does exactly what you are asking for.

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of node access modules available for Drupal but I honestly am not sure if there is one that would do exactly what you are looking for.

Either way, I would probably avoid a specific node access module for this and use Panels - read the Panels module - to do this since its makes this scenario easy to accomplish.

You can easily override Drupal's standard Node template and create an invariant that matches both the content/node type you want to apply this rule on and add a condition that the logged in user's ID matches the user id in the reference field defined by the node.